# Alignment issue in IOS webview

Tags: ios, webview, alignment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnq0d.png)
when loading in IOS web view it shows alignment issue, but in web it works prefectly

Comment: Please explain in more detail. What does your code look like?

Comment: Please check above image. At the bottom div start date and end date shows correctly in android web view but when I run this in iOS webview it's shows only half after that the scroll bott working. Note: it's html and CSS code not swift or objective c

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. This may help. 
This code will fit web view in any of the view with proper constraints.

```
import WebKit
    var viewOfWeb : WKWebView?
    let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    viewOfWeb = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
    viewOfWeb?.uiDelegate = self
    viewOfWeb?.navigationDelegate = self
    self.viewOfWebView?.addSubview(viewOfWeb ?? WKWebView())
    AppModelUtils.sharedInstance.setConstraint(subView: viewOfWeb ?? WKWebView(), RelateviveToSecondView: viewOfWebView)
    if let url = URL(string: urlString){
                let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.stopSpinner()
                    self.webView.load(request)
                }
            }
      }    


func setConstraint(subView: UIView ,RelateviveToSecondView superView:UIView)
    {
        subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let constX:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: superView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
        superView.addConstraint(constX);

        let constY:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem:superView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
        superView.addConstraint(constY);

        let constW:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: superView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
        superView.addConstraint(constW);

        let constH:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: superView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
        superView.addConstraint(constH);          
     }
```